# Deploy IBM Client Access V7r1 Silently

Tags: deployment, client, ibm-midrange, silent-installer

I try to deploy IBM Client Access V7r1 to multiple computers on the network

Silent installation doesn't work for me.

I created a patch file as:

```
@echo off
net use x: /delete
net use x: \\Path Of client setup file

x:

setup /s /v"REBOOT=REALLYSUPPRESS ADDLOCAL=ALL CWBADDSECLANG=ALL /qn" /l "c:\v7log.txt"
```

I try to deploy this patch through PDQ deploy, but the problem is that the setup doesn't run silently and asks me to complete the GUI setup.

Is there any way to make it run silently?

Comment: Hi AAA, your question is probably a better fit for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/). StackOverflow is geared towards software development while Server Fault is more appropriate for questions related to System/Network Administration.

Comment: Thank Benny i will forward it to there